# How to get the picture size in pygame (python)

Tags: python, image, pygame

If I'm using an image and I want to know the image's size **in the file**.

There is a function to get **the picture's** height and width ?

EDIT: Of course I loaded the image to the program with pygame.image.load(PATH).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to load the image as a Surface before you can get its width and height. You do that with `foo = pygame.image.load(PATHNAME)`.

Then you can get the width and height by creating a Rectangle with foo.get_rect() and asking the rectangle.

Comment: You can use the property `foo.get_rect().size` to save a step.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame
foo = pygame.image.load(PATH).get_rect().size
print(foo)
```

Return the size in a tupple