# PyGame - Getting the size of a loaded image

Tags: python, image, oop, pygame

**Hello, even though you might think there was a similar question, mine is pretty different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840711/how-to-get-the-picture-size-in-pygame-python).**

I am trying to load an image from a directory, and set my screen size (automatically) to the size of the image being loaded as "background".

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

image_resources = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pygame App/image_resources/"

class load:
    def image(self, image):
        self.image = image
        return (image_resources + image)
    def texture(self, texture):
        self.texture = texture
        return (image_resources + texture)

bg = load().image("bg_solid_black.jpg")

pygame.init()

#screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)

#background = pygame.image.load(bg).convert()

#width = background.get_width()
#height = background.get_height()
```

The image that I loaded with my "load()" class is set to the variable "bg" and I want to use the size of whatever I load as "bg" to determine the size of the window. If you try to move

```
background = pygame.image.load(bg).convert()

width = background.get_width()
height = background.get_height()
```

On top of this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
```

PyGame returns an error, in which it states that the display mode is not set. If I do it like this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(bg).convert()

width = background.get_width()
height = background.get_height()
```

of course, this is not true, since variables "width" and "height" are not defined for the use of "pygame.display.set_mode()".

I can not seem to figure this out, I though of solving through an OO manner, but I just can not seem to figure it out. Any help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before you use `convert()` on any surface, screen has to be initialized with `set_mode()`.

You can load image and get its size before `set_mode()` but `convert()` has to be used **after** you initialize the display, like so:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

image = pygame.image.load("file_to_load.jpg")

print(image.get_rect().size) # you can get size

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(image.get_rect().size, 0, 32)

image = image.convert() # now you can convert
```

Comment: You can cut a corner here by using `image.get_size()` instead of `image.get_rect().size`, forgoing the temporary `Rect` object.

Comment: @Augusta you can still write your own answer to this question :)

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't be meaningfully different from this one save maybe for the `get_size()` thing and a little bit of prose. It would be the same basic solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code I use is this:

```
import pygame
import os
import random


WIDTH = 750
HEIGHT = 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#Image Load
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background_space.png"))
```